# Как добавить данные после регистрации в базу данных sqlite3 в проекте Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite3

Не получается добавить именно в базу данных, данные методом POST получаются

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    login TEXT,
    passwor TEXT
)""")
db.commit()


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form['login']
        password = request.form['password']
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO users(login, password) VALUES(?, ?)", (login, password))
        db.commit()
        return render_template('menu.html')
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Для одного соединения можно создать неограниченное количество cursor. Он также не является потокобезопасным. Модуль не позволяет делиться объектами cursor между потоками. Если это сделать, то будет ошибка.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form['login']
        password = request.form['password']

        sqlc = db.cursor()
        sqlc.execute("INSERT INTO users(login, password) VALUES(?, ?)", (login, password))
        sqlc.close()
        db.commit()
        return render_template('menu.html')
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
```